# Tipo de campo Date Field en python?

Tags: python, django

Tengo una tabla que tiene un campo de **fecha** que recoge solamente la fecha. Mi duda es cómo especificar el formato en el que va a entrar esa fecha. Si éste es el formato `01 MAR 2016`, ¿cómo le especifico que es día, mes y año ?

**Ejemplo**: `fecha = models.DateField(null=False, max_length=50)`

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo settings.py

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y',)
```

Y en tu clase

```
 fecha = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

Pero tienes que tener este valor a false, para evitar que ocupe localización:

```
USE_L10N = False
```

Comment: Las tuplas de un elemento deben tener una coma al final aunque en versiones recientes es una lista.

Comment: @César tienes razón, gracias.

Comment: ¡No hay problema!

Comment: y esto DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y',) lo escribiría en cualquier lugar del settings.py  ????